# Can't edit Xamarin .axml layout files with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Due to a version license restriction at work, I have to develop a Xamarin Android app using Visual Studio **2015**. I must say that using Visual Studio 2019 (Student version) on my personal computer everything works fine, but I can't develop with that license at work.

On my work computer, I have installed and updated the Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 extension, and using Java Runtime Environment v1.8.0_241 and Java Development Kit v1.8.0_231, as I read at so many guides, here my config:

[image: xamarin options]

I have created and empty Xamarin Android Project, with no more files than the empty project includes, and there is no code modified by my side. But I get this error when trying to open the .axml file.

"Connection to the layout renderer failed. This may be caused by a misconfiguration of Java."

Here the full error report:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/utils/ILogger
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.utils.ILogger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 7 more
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Exception in thread "main"
```

Last line about "ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m" is due to a environment variable I created following guides, but now I have run out of options :/

I'm questioning if it is even possible to develop with Xamarin using Visual Studio 2015 or I have to ask my boss to upgrade license.

I appreciate any support. Thanks.

Comment: 2019 community also allows commercial usage for small teams ("In non-enterprise organizations, up to five users can use Visual Studio Community"), so install 2019 community edition. 2015 is too old.

Comment: Agree with  magicandre1981, VS 2015 is too old, please install VS 2019 to make a test(You can use Community version to make a test).https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ , you can use Android Studio to make a test as well, If you set the same JDK, SDK between AS and VS.

Comment: I have VS 2019 (A Student version) at home and I can modify .axml with no problems. But my enterprise need for me to work with VS 2015, cause they don't have license for 2019 and prices are not affordable. They want me to develop a very simple-experimental app for employees-internal use only. Anyway, you think is VS 2019 totally required or is it possible to work with VS 2017?

Comment: You can work with VS2017 as well. Please keep the VS 2017 version to the latest.

Comment: lol I have tried to edit the .xml files (the UI design) using Android Studio, and then copy the code to the .axml in VS 2015, and it works! I keep reserching and commenting, thanks for all your support guys.

Comment: post your steps as answer

Comment: Ok, I don't think it is the best solution but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have encountered as far:

I'm editing the .xml files (the UI designs) using Android Studio, then copy the code to the .axml in Visual Studio 2015, and now it works. My application is very simple, I only have Button, TextView and EditText, and it is enought for me.

If you have a more scalable solution, avoiding to use an external tool (Android Studio) my vote is yours.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. Please mark your reply as answer. It will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: How can I mark my answer as "the answer"? I can just vote up or down. Now I am pretty sure it is not possible to edit UI designs with VS 2015, but is it possible with VS 2017 and 2019

Comment: Could you found this “✔” in the upper right corner of your answer? You can click the “✔” to mark it as answer.